# Character of induced representation - problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup and let $X_H$ be a representation of $H$. According to the book *Algebra* by Cohn the character of the representation of $G$ induced by $H$ is given by
$$\tag{1}
\chi_G(x)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{y\in G}\dot{\chi}_H(yxy^{-1})
$$
where
$$
\dot{\chi}_H(z):=
\begin{cases}
    \chi_H(x), & \text{if } x\in H,\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}.
$$
Consider the alternating group $A_4$ with 4 conjugacy classes, containing elements
$$
(1)\in K_1,\qquad (12)(34)\in K_2,\qquad (123)\in K_3,\qquad (132)\in K_4.
$$
The cyclic group generated by $(123)$ is a subgroup, and its character table is given by

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\, & (1) & (123) & (132)\\
\hline
\chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\chi_2 & 1 & e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i} & e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i} \\
\chi_3 & 1 & e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i} & e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}
\end{array}$$

Now I want to try and calculate $\chi_2^{A_4}(1)$ of the induced representation using Equation $(1)$, but I get
$$
\chi_2^{A_4}(1)=\frac{1}{3}(\dot{\chi_2}(1)+3\dot{\chi_2}(1)+4\dot{\chi_2}(123)+4\dot{\chi_2}(132))=\frac{1}{3}(1+3+4e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}+4e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i})=0
$$
(where each term in the second equality is multiplied by the size of the respective conjugacy class) This is not a useful character of $A_4$ so what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I think I might have found the issue. $\dot{\chi}_H(y(1)y^{-1})$ is equal to zero except for the following cases
$$
\begin{aligned}
&y=(1),\qquad y(1)y^{-1}=(1),\\
&y\in K_2,\qquad y(1)y^{-1}=(1),\\
&y=(123),\qquad y(1)y^{-1}=(123),\\
&y=(132),\qquad y(1)y^{-1}=(132).
\end{aligned}
$$

Using Eq. $(1)$, I then get
$$
\chi_2^{A_4}(1)=\frac{1}{3}(\chi_H(1)+3\chi_H(1)+\chi_H(123)+\chi_H(132))=\frac{1}{3}(4+e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}+e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i})=1,
$$
which indicates that the induced representation is of degree 1.

Comment: It looks like your mistake is with conjugation. If $x = 1$, then $yxy^{-1} = 1$ for all $y \in G$.

Comment: @DanielArreola, check my edit

Comment: How are you getting $y1y^{-1} = (123)$ when $y = (123)$?

Comment: @DanielArreola, you are right. Then I get that $\chi_2^{A_4}(1)=4$, which may be correct.

Comment: That's correct. In general, if a representation of $H$ has degree $d$, then the induced representation on $G$ will have degree $|G : H| \cdot d$.

Comment: @DanielArreola, that's useful information, thank you.